# Sluggish performance in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: 14.04, fonts, gnome-terminal

I work on two `1900x1200` monitors, usually with at least one monitor running a fullscreen terminal window. I use a font size of `Ubuntu mono 10`.

I have noticed that performance is sluggish (I am using an i7, 16gb ram, etc.). For example, when I run `ls` on a large local directory, the text wobbles down over a second or so. Running the same command from a TTY terminal or reducing the size of the `tmux` pane in which the command is run makes the same command run almost instantly.

What can I do to improve the performance of the ubuntu terminal? Or are there better performing alternatives to the default? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your problem reproduce under different conditions?

Can you reproduce the problem under different conditions and benchmark the time it takes to perform various operations (ex: time cat largefile.txt). Example scenarios:

- using `GNU screen` instead of tmux;
- without using a terminal multiplexor;
- using another terminal emulator (tilda, terminator, rxvt or xterm for example);
- using a different font such as *Envy Code R*, *DejaVu Mono* or *Droid Sans Mono*;

I personally like `tilda` quite a lot as a terminal emulator (fullscreen and all) and don't experience any kind of performance problems. You can bind it to a hotkey like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>, similar to the terminal in Quake.

I'm sure you can get a lot more scientific with SystemTap or Valgrind, but depends how much effort you want to invest in this...

Comment: Yeah, not a lot! Thanks for the response though, I'll give tilda a go.